# Analysis of mcmc output

Tags: interpretation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I have a sequence of Bayesian Networks for del with more epochs. For example if i work with trafic on street I can have a BN for morning, one for afternoon e one for evening.

If i collect data for 24h, when end the morning and start the afternoon ? when end the afternoon and start the evening? when end the evening and start the morning?

Here I use a Metropolis Hastings where the state is a configuration oftransition time. I start with uniform distribution of the transition time (evening 00:00-8:00, morning 8:00-16:00, Afternoon 16:00-00:00) an then I shift one transition at time for iteration (for example 16:00 to 16:30). When I do one shift I can use the score (for example BD score) for evaluate the new state. In pratice the state of Metropolis Hastings is the configuration of transition time.

Remove the burn in, using thinning for avoid autocorreletion between near state, and after that the algorithm converges i have an output like this:

```
00:00 for 8 times
...
8:00 56 times
..
9:15 18 times
..
16:00
..
16:03 9 times
..
17:31 10 times
```

Where ".." is more other output.

How i can get the more likely transition time? If i get all the local maximum if i have noise i can get more then (3 epochs + 1) transition time.

For example if I have:

```
7:59 4 times
8:00 51 times
8:01 6 times
8:02 20 times
8:03 7 times
```

I have 8:00 and 8:02 as local maximum, but this is noise. With a graphical analysis it's simple to notice this, but there is a numerical approach to do this?